# How to get reCaptcha Token?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

How do I get this token google reCAPTCHA needs to send a request to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify  ?

The documentation is not very clear:

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify
- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Everything I read is using various React npm programs. I don't want to use them, shouldn't really have to for such a simple thing.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction?

```
const MyPage = () => {

  const [reCaptchaVerified, setReCaptchaVerified] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {

    let captchaToken = '';                                          // How to get the reCaptcha Token?
    let captchaResult = GoogleReCaptcha(captchaToken);              // My Backend. Sends the token and secret key to google's API.
    
    if(captchaResult === true){
        setReCaptchaVerified(true);
    }
    else {
        setReCaptchaVerified(false);
    }
  }

  return (
    <form id="my-form" onSubmit="handleSubmit()">
        <button type="submit" disabled={!reCaptchaVerified} data-sitekey={ RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY } data-callback='onSubmit' data-action='my-form-submit'>Submit</button>
    </form>
    <footer>
        {/* Google ReCaptcha Script  */}
        <Script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></Script>
        <Script>
            {`function onSubmit(token) {
                document.getElementById("my-form").submit();
            } `}
        </Script>
    </footer>
  )
}
```

I must be missing something in either the google scripts or a tag on the submit button? Or is the token included in the form's event? event.token?

I read about grecaptcha.getResponse() being used ??? But I see no examples.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Why is this not answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reCaptcha 3 this is working for me.

in the head of my page.

```html
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=SITE_KEY"></script>
```

Lower in my document.

```html
<button onclick='someAction()'>Some Action</button>
```

and finally. The function that gets the token.

```js
function someAction() {
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
        grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got reCaptcha V2 working:

```
// Get Google ReCaptcha Score
let captchaToken = grecaptcha.getResponse();
```

That got me the token. It does say to use it on their website, but it doesn't show it in an example, so I wasn't sure how it all clicked together.

*"grecaptcha.getResponse(opt_widget_id) after the user completes the reCAPTCHA challenge"*

You could also do:

let captchaToken = = req.body["g-recaptcha-response"];

For reCaptcha V3 I have still no idea how to get the token...